# Is there any way to fetch what users are mapped to a policy tag in BigQuery through python/APIs?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-security

In BigQuery, to implement column level access control, we make the use of policy tags.
I have created a taxonomy under which I have created a policy tag, let's say P1.

I can apply this tag onto any column in a table of my choice to restrict access to that specific column. After that only the users I associate with the policy tag P1, will be able to access that column.

I know how to see the view/manage the list of users through the console, when I go to policy tags  section and click on the specific tag.

Through the client.get_table method I am even able to get what policy is applied to what column on a table when I list the schema. But I am unable to fetch the list of users associated with that policy.

Note: This policy is different from an IAM policy which gives users access to a project/dataset/table or even a row based access policy.

Comment: Did you try this API? https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.dataTaxonomies/getIamPolicy

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I tried this api but it keeps telling me that the location is invalid/doesn't exist. I am using an account with the Owner role so permissions should not be an issue. The dataplex API is also enabled. And if the resource name of my policy tag is "projects/project_1/locations/asia-south2/taxonomies/123123123/policyTags/456456456". I am making the API call with the resource parameter as "projects/project_1/locations/asia-south2/dataTaxonomies/123123123"